How to customize the login page for Spring Security with both form and OAuth2 authentication?
Spring Boot 3.2.4 and Spring Security 6.2.3
I have enabled both OAuth2 and form login in an app using a configuration like this:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final MyUserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;


    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MyOAuth2UserService oauth2Service) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(this::configureAuthorization)
            .oauth2Login(c -> configureOAuth2(c, oauth2Service))
            .formLogin(this::configureFormLogin)
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())   // Used for APIs when called other than from the UI
            .logout(this::configureLogout)
            ;

        return http.build();
    }

    private void configureAuthorization(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry authorize) {
        authorize
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()

            .requestMatchers("/*/*.js", "/*/*/*.js", "/css/**", "/lib/**", "/assets/**", "favicon.ico").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/restrictedStuff/**").hasAnyRole("GOOD_GUY")
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    private void configureOAuth2(OAuth2LoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity> oauthLogin, MyOAuth2UserService userService) {
        oauthLogin
            .userInfoEndpoint(endpoint -> endpoint.oidcUserService(userService))
            //.loginPage("/login")
            ;
    }

    private void configureFormLogin(FormLoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity> formLogin) {
        formLogin
            //.loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
    }

    private void configureLogout(LogoutConfigurer<HttpSecurity> logout) {
        logout
            .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_PAGE)
            .permitAll();
    }

}


This works as expected, with the /login page being auto-generated with both a user/password form and providing the "Login with OAuth 2.0" link for my OIDC provider (Google).
Now I need to use a custom login page for the form and OAuth2 link. That's what I can't get working.
In the code snippet above I have calls to loginPage("/login") commented out; I tried uncommenting either and both of those (along with a standard "/login" endpoint in an MVC controller), but that yields strange/broken results.
What's the correct way to use a custom login page in this authentication setup?

If you are making a Spring MVC app with some kind of template engine like Freemarker or Thymeleaf, your Controller class manages which page to use for login. This is a sample controller:
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "/auth/login";
    }
}

"/auth/login" is a directory. For example, if in your templates folder you have sub-folder called "auth" and there you have your login.html file.
I hope it makes sense.

I think you misunderstood the question. I can't get Spring to use my custom page to show the login form and the button to log in with Google. Spring either only uses it's own generated page or doesn't work at all.

Consider creating a separate SecurityFilterChain bean with lower order (e.g., @Order(2)) to isolate your login configuration. This lets you manage login-related settings without impacting other security rules.
@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(
                            "/login",
                            "/error",
                            "/webjars/**",
                            "/images/**",
                            "/css/**",
                            "/assests/**",
                            "/actuator/**",
                            "/favicon.ico")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
            // authorization server filter chain
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()
                        login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
            );

    return http.build();
}

If you're interested in further details on customizing the consent form as well, you can refer to this configuration file: SecurityConfiguration.java, where I experimented with OAuth2. You can also explore the repository here.
